# Universal application UI issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uipopovercontroller

Im creating universal application.

In my iPhone application : I've created custom screen to inform user about the progress of the background progress. Im adding that view controller using segue and it occupies the whole screen.

In my iPad application : I'm using UIPopoverController which is calling the ViewController which shows the progress. **However, in iPad also it occupies the whole screen. Where as I want it to occupy only the screen of UIPopoverController.** Im not able to understand how should I add the screen so that it'll only hide the last UIPopoverController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
- (IBAction)onShare:(id)sender
{
UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
SocialNetworkView *socialNetworkShare = [[SocialNetworkView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SocialNetworkView" bundle:nil];

socialNetworkShare.delegate=self;
//---------------------------contentSizeForViewInPopover------------------
//set required size in contentSizeForViewInPopover in your view controller
socialNetworkShare.contentSizeForViewInPopover  =CGSizeMake(socialNetworkShare.view.frame.size.width, socialNetworkShare.view.frame.size.height);  


popSocialNetworkShare = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:socialNetworkShare];

[popSocialNetworkShare presentPopoverFromRect:btn.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:YES animated:YES];
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:` for popover creation and pass your view controller into `initWithContentViewController`. Also, set required size in`self.contentSizeForViewInPopover` in your view controller